# Execution on Selenium HQ Remote browser redirecting to a different than requested

Tags: java, selenium-grid, qaf

I'm executing tests in selenium HQ with few capabilities, even though the capabilities are correct few times instead of selecting browser based on the capability's client send it is attempting the tests in a different browser. The actual capability after driver gets created are with a different browser than what client requested for.

The redirecting of browser is happening after connection to selenium hq is happened. So, I'm thinking it's not our code issue because the same code works fine at times. but when we run multiple tests (capabilities client passes looks good) instead of desired browser other browser is being set for execution. And getting hung from there.

When execution started with on Selenium HQ remote Microsoft Edge browser, test should start on the same browser. Could someone please assist with this?